# Por que motivo o país Cameroun, situado na África Ocidental, veio a ser chamado "Camarões" pelos portugueses?

Tags: tradução

A República dos Camarões é um país situado na África Ocidental. Seus habitantes nativos, falantes de Duala, Ewondo ou Fula, as principais línguas nativas, chamam sua pátria de **Kamerun** ou **Kamerún**. Colonizado por franceses e ingleses, teve seu nome traduzido por **Cameroun** e **Cameroon**, respectivamente nas duas línguas. Em nenhuma das línguas citadas acima, o nome daquele país significa **camarão** ou **camarões**.

Addendum - Quando do encontro de suas seleções de futebol, os brasileiros costumam dizer para os camaronêses que vão almoçar camarões naquele dia. Os camaronêses não entendem a brincadeira e sentem-se insultados, respondendo que o nome de seu país nada tem a ver com camarões.

Comment: Não tenho o background historico para responder, mas seria pelo mesmo motivo de chamarmos Japão como chamamos não? Foi uma adaptação para a pronuncia da lingua local.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira   "Japão" é bem semelhante ao que é chamado em outras línguas.  É Japan em croata, dinamarquês, holandês, inglês. É "japón" em espanhol.  É Japonsko em tcheco, e em português "Japão".  Seria cômico se tivesse sido denominado "jagonça".

Comment: Adaptação para a pronuncia local ?  Não temos nenhuma dificuldade com Cameron, Camerun, Camerão, Cameru, etc.  Não precisava ser "camarões".

Comment: Mais difícil de pronunciar para o falante de português, é o nome de países como a Suazilândia, Zimbábue, Djibuti, etc. e, nem por isso seus nomes foram modificados para algo mais fácil.

Comment: Creio então que tenha sido por algum outro motivo.  Quem sabe a "República dos Camarões" não tem uma grande produção desses crustáceos ?

Comment: nos nao teriamos nenhuma dificuldade em pronunciar nippon também, assim como japon e japan, são todas pronuncias possiveis em portugues. Porem pela resposta parece ter um motivo historico...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camar%C3%B5es#Povos_ind%C3%ADgenas,_chegada_dos_europeus_e_coloniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e a [Encyclopædia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/place/Wouri-River), é porque o nome tem origem em português, não em outra língua. O Fernão do Pó / Fernando Pó, no século XV, chamou o Rio Vuri o «Rio dos Camarões», por motivo dos camarões que ele encontrou neste rio.